# Review Stars zero

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

My app recently made it to the app-store([Planner!](http://appsto.re/us/TWbsP.i)) and three users gave it reviews. However the stars are not filled. Anyone no why? Here is a pic:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen it documented anywhere, but my impression is that only apps with a large number of reviews get colored in stars.

The app in question still has no reviews that have aged in long enough (or numbers enough) to get a summary yet. My guess is that after a certain number of reviews (around 100 by my experience) an application will get a summary update on the store. Also, there is probably a timer (maybe 30 days) when the ratings will get solidified and drawn in solidly.

In this case, it looks like you'll want to wait until 20 to 50 reviews are added and three weeks have passed and then see if the ratings are updated as you expect.

Another possibility is that the reviewers gave you zero stars and good words which seems less likely, but possible as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I do not think it is the first case because I saw a bunch of apps that were new and had about 4 reviews have normal stars.

Comment: And it is very unlikely for the second case because all three users cannot all say nice things and give a zero stars(If that is even possible).

Comment: I just confirmed and I found out that the minimum is 5 stars! Thanks!

Comment: Excallent - you can edit that detail into my answer (anyone is free to edit another's posts to make them better). Good luck with your app.